# Joining two tables with sub-queries from one

Tags: mysql

My database features multiple groups that host events at one or more venues. Most times it is just the one venue, but groups will sometimes have two.
To keep things simple, the following data set is small and imaginary:

'groups' table

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| name         | pri_venue_id | alt_venue_id |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| Fast Fingers |            3 |            0 |
| Data Dishers |            4 |            0 |
| Leet Hacks   |            5 |            2 |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

'venues' table

```
+----------+-------------------------+-----------------+
| venue_id | name                    | location        |
+----------+-------------------------+-----------------+
|        1 | Public Archives         | Querytown       |
|        2 | Storage Function Centre | Drive Bay       |
|        3 | Key Convention Centre   | Qwertyville     |
|        4 | Head-spin Mall          | Drive Park      |
|        5 | Fast Storage Facility   | Memory Bay      |
+----------+-------------------------+-----------------+
```

I want to join the two tables together in a single query, such that the result of the query will display the group, the primary venue name and location, and the second venue and location if there is one.
In the case that there is no second/alternative venue, just show the primary, then two NULLS, like so:

```
Data Dishers, Head-spin Mall, Drive Park, NULL, NULL
Fast Fingers, Key Convention Centre, Qwertyville, NULL, NULL
Leet Hacks, Fast Storage Facility, Memory Bay, Storage Function Centre, Drive Bay
```

Please note that the result set does not have to be comma-delimited.

I have read other stackoverflow questions, but have not yet found a solution. I keep getting either duplicate rows, or else everything but the alternative venue, which always displays NULL. I'm not sure what would be best to group by, as I saw this suggested in another question. Also tried using a union, but could not seem to get it to work.

Here is the closest query that I have come up with:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT groups. NAME,
    x. NAME,
    x.location,
    y. NAME,
    y.location
FROM groups
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        venues.*
    FROM venues
    INNER JOIN groups ON venue_id = pri_venue_id
) AS x,
groups
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        venues.*
    FROM venues
    LEFT JOIN groups ON venue_id = alt_venue_id
) AS y
GROUP BY x.venue_id
ORDER BY groups. NAME;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Turns out I did not need to use sub-queries to get the right results. The right query was: "SELECT g.name AS g_name,v1.name AS v_name,v1.location,v2.name AS v_name2,v2.location AS location2 FROM groups g INNER JOIN venues v1 ON g.pri_venue_id = v1.venue_id LEFT JOIN venues v2 ON g.alt_venue_id = v2.venue_id ORDER BY g.name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `INNER` and one `LEFT JOIN` together with `CONCAT` can do the trick:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT_WS(', ', `name`, `name1`, location1, name2, location2) groups 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            g.`name`,
            v1.`name` name1,
            v1.location location1,
            IF(v2.`name` IS NOT NULL, v2.`name`, 'NULL') name2,
            IF(v2.location IS NOT NULL, v2.location, 'NULL') location2
        FROM
            groups g
        INNER JOIN venues v1 ON v1.venue_id = g.pri_venue_id
        LEFT JOIN venues v2 ON v2.venue_id = g.alt_venue_id
        ORDER BY g.pri_venue_id
    ) x
```

Output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| groups                                                                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Fast Fingers, Key Convention Centre, Qwertyville, NULL, NULL                      |
| Data Dishers, Head-spin Mall, Drive Park, NULL, NULL                              |
| Leet Hacks, Fast Storage Facility, Memory Bay, Storage Function Centre, Drive Bay |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set
```

You can change `'NULL'` string with real `NULL` if you need.

Comment: Excellent! I should have been a bit clearer earlier, but I did not need the NULL to be a NULL string; an actual NULL value is fine.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an inner join and a left join. Like so...

```
select g.name, v1.name, v1.location, coalesce(v2.name, 'NULL'), coalesce(v2.location, 'NULL')
from groups g
inner join venues v1 on (g.pri_venue_id = v1.venue_id)
left join venues v2 on (g.alt_venue_id = v2.venue_id)
```

The coalesce function basically just converts `null` values into the string NULL

Comment: Not bad, as it achieved most of the strings that I needed. However, this appears to have the side-effect of giving the key names "coalesce(v2.name,'NULL')" and "coalesce(v2.address,'NULL')" to every venue name and address element, in the array returned. I also needed the result set to be sorted by the name of the groups. There was also a naming conflict between the two name fields, preventing the group name from showing. This is easily fixed by giving them a different alias each.